# grpc doesnt compile my messages correctly

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, protoc

I am trying to compile my .proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package chat;

message Person {
  string name = 1;
  string family = 2;
  int32 age = 3;
}

message SearchPerson {
  string name = 1;
}

service PersonService {
  rpc GetPerson (SearchPerson) returns (Person) {}
  rpc GetPeople (SearchPerson) returns (stream Person) {}
}
```

and when I ran this command:

```
./bin/protoc --go-grpc_out=. ./proto/person.proto
```

a new file created for me (person_grpc.pb.go)
but I have a error for my messages and services:

```
UnResolved Type for SearchPerson
```

and you can see that new file give me error (Unresolved type) for my messages and services.
What is problem?

Comment: Can you rename your package in the proto file to something other than `grpc`? This might conflict with the `grpc` package import.

Comment: i changed package to communication and tried again and nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add the `go_package` directive in your files ([as described in the doc](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated#invocation)) that ideally reflect your package/project path, as example:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package chat;

option go_package = "example.com/foo/chat";

// option go_package = "chat";


message Person {
  string name = 1;
  string family = 2;
  int32 age = 3;
}
```

Then change your script accordingly

```
./bin/protoc --go-grpc_out=./chat ./proto/person.proto
```

Then you should be able to use from the `chat` package of your project